# Service (factory) error - json api not displaying data

Tags: angularjs

I have spent like a good 4 to 6 hours on trying to solve my issue - maybe I am looking at it completely wrong.

`controller.js` file:

```
'use strict';

/* Controllers */

var bookControllers = angular.module('bookControllers', []);

bookControllers.controller('BookListCtrl', ['$scope', 'Book',
  function($scope, Book) {
    $scope.books = Book.query();
    $scope.orderProp = 'name';
  }]);

bookControllers.controller('BookDetailCtrl', ['$scope', '$routeParams', 'Book',
  function($scope, $routeParams, Book) {
    $scope.book = Book.get({bookId: $routeParams.bookId}, function(book) {
      $scope.mainImageUrl = book.avatar;
    });

    $scope.setImage = function(imageUrl) {
      $scope.mainImageUrl = imageUrl;
    };
  }]);
```

My `service.js` file

```
'use strict';

/* Services */

var bookServices = angular.module('bookServices', ['ngResource']);

bookServices.factory('Book', ['$resource',
  function($resource){
    return $resource('https://api.myjson.com/bins/1oofv', {}, {
      query: {method:'GET', params:{bookId:'bookId'}, isArray:true}
    });
  }]);
```

So what is happening.

My `SHOW` file - which displays all `books` within my `book.json` file which I have hosted on myjson displays all the content I need.

It displays all thumbnails accordingly with the following html:

```
<div class="container">
<!--Nav Bar-->
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
      Find me the best
      <select ng-model="orderProp" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown">
        <option value="name">Alphabetical</option>
        <option value="age">Newest</option>
      </select>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-4">
      Books about
      <select ng-model="orderProp" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenu1" data-toggle="dropdown">
        <option ng-repeat="book in books" value="">{{ book.genre.name }}</option>
      </select>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="input-group">
        <input ng-model="query" type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search books">
          <span class="input-group-btn">
            <button class="btn btn-default" type="button"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search" ></span></button>
          </span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

<!--Body content-->
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4" ng-repeat="book in books | filter:query | orderBy:orderProp">
      <div class="thumbnail" id="books">
        <a href="#/books/{{ book.name }}"><img ng-src="{{ book.cover }}"></a>
        <div class="caption">
          <h4>{{ book.name }}</h4>
          <h5><a href="{{ book.id }}">{{ book.author.name }}</a></h5>
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-heart likes">{{ book.likes }}</span>
          <span style="float: right;">{{ book.published | date:'yyyy-MM-dd' }}</span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

This is all fine - now when I click a specific book or author I am expecting the app to nav to the next page a detail ALL the details I need in the following template (but it doesn't):

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
  <header>
    <h1></h1>
    <h4></h4>
    <p></p>
    <h6>Categories:</h6>
    <span>{{ book.genre.category }}</span>
  </header>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <h3>Introduction</h3>
  <h1></h1>
  <p></p>
  <div class="line-sep"></div>
  <img ng-src="{{ avatar }}" class="img-round" />
  <h2></h2>
</div>

<div class="row">
  <h1>Similar reading</h1>
  <p></p>
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="thumbnail" id="books">
      <a href="#"><img ng-src="http://placehold.it/350x500"></a>
      <div class="caption">
        <h4>Lorem Ipsum Dolar Asar</h4>
        <h5><a href="#">By Mr Lorem Ipsum</a></h5>
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-heart likes">1032</span>
        <span style="float: right;">3 days ago</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="thumbnail" id="books">
      <a href="#"><img ng-src="http://placehold.it/350x500"></a>
      <div class="caption">
        <h4>Lorem Ipsum Dolar Asar</h4>
        <h5><a href="#">By Mr Lorem Ipsum</a></h5>
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-heart likes">1032</span>
        <span style="float: right;">3 days ago</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="thumbnail" id="books">
      <a href="#"><img ng-src="http://placehold.it/350x500"></a>
      <div class="caption">
        <h4>Lorem Ipsum Dolar Asar</h4>
        <h5><a href="#">By Mr Lorem Ipsum</a></h5>
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-heart likes">1032</span>
        <span style="float: right;">3 days ago</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Look at my josn file on the site: https://api.myjson.com/bins/1oofv

All I need to do is the following:

Use the json file to display the books (with some details) on the `list` page - in whatever display style I feel is appropriate.

Then - once all the books are displayed (with search and filter abilities) - be able to click on a book and be taken to a `BOOK DETAIL` page where we will delve into more detail about the book and show books that are similar to them.

Comment: You're just setting href="{{book.id}}". That doesn't seem right. Can you show your different routes you have setup?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

stop stressing, and follow the [Flatlander Gemstore tutorial](http://campus.codeschool.com/courses/shaping-up-with-angular-js/).

1. First problem I could spot is, you use `Book.get` but defined `Book.query`
2. Secondly, using `href="#"` breaks angular, either use an `<a href="">`or, as I prefer, simply use a button, a hyperlink that goes nowhere isn't a link.
3. as yeouuu said, `href="{{ book.id }}"` seems wrong, this is either a semantical error and should be `href="{{ book.url }}"` or this is simply an error and should have been something else entirely.

Do the tutorial, it is a great resource.

Comment: thanks - I will check it out. So many resources that I seemed to learn the wrong things from each. I tried using the "phoencatApp" example form angular to create the app i needed.

Comment: It's not so much wrong, the phone-app works, and is a good resource, but I found that the Gemstore went deeper faster. Because of the fact that it is interactive combined with screencasts, I found it easier to follow. Another great resource is [Papa Johns Angular Styleguide](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide), at work we based our codestyle on his work, but took it a step further on some fronts.